# HOWTO: Fire an event when mouse is on one of the sides and corners of a WPF border

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, border

Basically I have an WPF border and I would like to fire an event when mouse is on one of the sides and corners:

- Left
- Top-Left corner
- Bottom-Left corner
- Right
- Top-Right corner
- Bottom-Right corner
- Top
- Bottom

I need to detect when mouse is on each of them in order to fire different events.

How can I do this?

Comment: Must it be on the border, or is it acceptable to surround the border with other controls that can then fire if the mouse is on top of them? The other controls (possibly other borders) would be located at the locations you listed above.

Comment: @redcurry It must be on border only, It has a borderthickness="1" and borderbrush="LightBlue".

Comment: Is that the only reason it must be on the border? You can still get the same effect by putting these "edge" controls on top of the border at the correct locations.

Comment: @redcurry ok, could you explain me in detail how? could you provide me a little example?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of detecting the mouse events directly on the `Border`, you can put a layer of controls on top of the `Border` and detect the mouse events on them. The easiest way to put this layer is to use a `Grid`, and use simple `Border`s as the controls:

```
<Grid>
    <!-- Your border -->
    <Border
        BorderThickness="1"
        BorderBrush="LightBlue"
        Width="100" Height="100"
        >
        <!-- Contents -->
    </Border>

    <Grid
        Width="100" Height="100"
        >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="5" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="5" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
            Background="Transparent"
            MouseEnter="OnMouseEnterTopLeft"
            />
        <Border
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
            Background="Transparent"
            MouseEnter="OnMouseEnterTop"
            />
        <Border
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
            Background="Transparent"
            MouseEnter="OnMouseEnterTopRight"
            />
        <Border
            Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
            Background="Transparent"
            MouseEnter="OnMouseEnterLeft"
            />
        <Border
            Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
            Background="Transparent"
            MouseEnter="OnMouseEnterRight"
            />
        <Border
            Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
            Background="Transparent"
            MouseEnter="OnMouseEnterBottomLeft"
            />
        <Border
            Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
            Background="Transparent"
            MouseEnter="OnMouseEnterBottom"
            />
        <Border
            Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"
            Background="Transparent"
            MouseEnter="OnMouseEnterBottomRight"
            />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Notice that the sizes of the `Border` and `Grid` must be the same so that they align perfectly. They don't need to be a fixed size like I've shown here; they may stretch inside their container.

In the `Grid` definitions for rows and columns, I've chosen a detection size of 5 pixels, but of course you can choose whatever size you want. Also, each `Border` inside the `Grid` must have its `Background` set to `Transparent`; otherwise, the mouse event is not detected.